# Git doesn't recognise new .h, .m and .xib files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, atlassian-sourcetree

We have an objective c project, which works fine all the time and suddenly cannot recognise any new added .h .m or .xib files. But if I add new .metal file, it will work fine....

Here is the test we did

We added TestNewViewController and File.metal inside our project
[image: We added TestNewViewController and File.metal inside our project]

But inside the source tree I cannot find the new file record for TestNewViewController
[image: But inside the source tree I cannot find the new file record for TestNewViewController]

We could find this update in project.pbxproj file
[image: We could find this update in project.pbxproj file]

And also we could find these files inside Finder
[image: And also we could find these files inside Finder]

This project is under development within several different Mac Book Pro.. Only one computer has this issue.

The problem of this issue is that whenever the computer with problem commit any changes involving new files, other computers cannot retrieve these new files from Cloud. Because the computer with problem never push these new files to Cloud.....

Comment: Just feel like this is something wrong with this computer... we find out all of our projects inside this computer have the same issue.

Comment: Did you check your git ignores are fine? I mean, with the files/extensions you want to ignore. Maybe that pc in particular has different gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely those files are git ignored. Use the `git check-ignore` command to debug gitignore / exclude files.

```
git check-ignore <path_to_missing_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to see if any file format is in .gitignore

```
git check-ignore -v your_files_path
```

Where -v gives more details [(verbose).](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)